# Selenium PHP get url of a link tag

Tags: php, selenium, xpath

my php class extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.

How can I get the url from an xpath?

For example, my xpath for the link is this: `//html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a`

The link does not have an id. How can I get the url???

I tried `$this>getValue("//html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a");`

but apparently that only works for form fields. I found a getAttribute function and tried the following (all failed):

```
$this->getAttribute("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a");
$this->getAttribute("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]");
$this->getAttribute("//html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a");
$this->getAttribute("//html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]");
$this->getAttribute("/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a");
$this->getAttribute("/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]");
```

I don't understand. The selenium id seems to work with the following:

Command: storeAttribute
Target: xpath=/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a
Value: varname

Please help! And a link to some documentation I could refer to later would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the link's href attribute. Try:

```
$this->getAttribute("//html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/@href");
```

Comment: Thank you Goat Master! This is exactly what I needed. And now that I have this model I can find any other attribute that I may be looking for. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "getAttribute":

```
$this->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('a'))->getAttribute("href");
```